# Need FileDialog with a file type filter in Java

Tags: java, swing, awt, filedialog

I have a JDialog with a button/textfield for the user to select a file.  Here's the code:

```
FileDialog chooser = new FileDialog(this, "Save As", FileDialog.SAVE );
String startDir = saveAsField.getText().substring( 0, saveAsField.getText().lastIndexOf('\\') );
chooser.setDirectory(startDir);
chooser.setVisible(true);
String fileName = chooser.getFile();
```

My problem is that instead of seeing an All Files filter, I want to provide a custom filter, e.g. for Word docs or something.  I setup a custom FilenameFilter using setFilenameFilter(), but it didn't seem to work.  I did notice that it says in the docs that the custom filter doesn't work in Windows (this runs in Windows XP/Vista/7).  Here was my implementation of the filter:

```
chooser.setFilenameFilter( new geFilter() );
public class geFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.endsWith( ".doc" ) || name.endsWith( ".docx" );
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?  Also, I want a description to appear in the box, like "Microsoft Word (*.doc *.docx)" but I'm not sure how to do that.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AWT isn't really the preferred way of writing Java GUI apps these days. Sun seems to have mostly abandoned it. The two most popular options are Swing and [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/). So I think they didn't really develop the APIs very extensively to add modern features. (err, to answer your question: No you don't appear to be able to do that with AWT)

Swing has the advantage that it is truly write-once-run-anywhere and it can look exactly the same everywhere. There are Look & Feels that try to make Swing look native, some are better than others (Mac isn't terrible, Windows is okay, GTK isn't). Still, if you want an app that really looks and acts EXACTLY the same everywhere, Swing will let you do that. Plus it runs out-of-the-box without any extra libraries. Performance isn't great.

Swing's [JFileChooser](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) will let you do what you want. Create a subclass of [FileFilter](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter.html) and call `setFileFilter` on the `JFileChooser`.

SWT takes the write-once-run-anywhere to the opposite extreme. You still have one codebase that you write against, but it actually uses the native widgets on each platform so it generally looks like a native app (not perfect everywhere, but still impressive). It's fast and pretty reliable in my experience. Eclipse (and other high profile software) uses SWT so it's in pretty heavy use. But it does require platform-specific JARs and DLLs.

Comment: This turned out to be the correct answer for me, and I even eventually figured out how to style the JFileChooser to match the rest of the app.  Apparently this just isn't possible with a FileDialog... that still makes me sad.

Comment: No offence, but the JFileChooser on Mac OS X just looks ugly you feel ashamed.

Comment: @Zizouz212 I don't think shame is the right emotion. Swing (out-of-the-box) doesn't look very good anywhere (JFileChooser and all other widgets included), though Mac is probably least bad. SWT is better but more (developer) work. It's not clear what platform the OP is using, but I think all of this is already implied by my answer.

Answer (score 5):

since you are using JDialog, that is a swing class why not using [JFileChooser](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html)?

```
 JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser("C:\\");
 fc.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Microsoft Word (*.doc, *.docx)", "doc", "docx"));
```

[FileNameExtensionFilter](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter.html) is a nice Java 6 class that does exactly what you want.

Comment: The reason I'm using FileDialog is that it perfectly matches the Windows look and feel and is also consistent with other dialogs in our application.  Can I make a JFileChooser that matches?

Answer (score 3):

I am also trying to do that. I want to use FileDialog instead of JFileChooser.

I found the answer here: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0247.html

He says that "on the Win platform, the setFilenameFilter method don't work. We must use the setFile method instead to set a filter."

There is source code at the specified link.

I tested and it works:

```
FileDialog fd = new FileDialog((Frame) null, "Save File", FileDialog.SAVE);
fd.setFile("*.txt");
fd.setVisible(true);

String file = fd.getFile();
System.out.println(file);
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: This has no effect. Im using MacOS

Answer (score 3):

If you ever use [JavaFX 2](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/), the [FileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html) class will do exactly what you need without any of JFileChooser/FileDialog problems. You can also embed JavaFX 2 components inside Swing applications, but you need [JavaFX runtime](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/index.html).

Example:

```
    FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter filter;
    filter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Text files (*.txt)", "*.txt");
    fc.getExtensionFilters().add(filter);
    File f = fc.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
    System.out.println(f);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call the native Windows Filedialog (CFileDialog) with JNI. Filters can be set for CFileDialog easily.

I wrote a simple wrapper class for CFileDialog several months ago, If you are interested, you can get the source and binary from

[Xfiledialog project on google code](http://code.google.com/p/xfiledialog/)

Answer (score -1):

Just use `setFilenameFilter` method of the `FileDialog` instance `fd`:

```
            fd.setFilenameFilter(new FilenameFilter()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public boolean accept(File file, String s)
                                {
                                    // enter code to return TRUE or FALSE here
                                    return s.contains(".txt");
                                }
                            });
```